# HttpException 400 SPARQL in Java

Tags: java, sparql, jena, dbpedia, virtuoso

I'm trying to write a query that will search dbpedia movies only and find movies with the keyword "Inception".  The query is working on http://dbpedia.org/sparql but not in my java code.  I'm using jena libraries.

This is my Query

```
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
select ?Concept where {
?Concept a dbpedia-owl:Film.
?Concept rdfs:label ?label. FILTER (strStarts(str(?label), 'Inception')). } limit 10
```

Here is my Java function

```
public static String extractDbpedia (String jenaString) {
    String result;
    String queryString =
            "prefix rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>" +
            "prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>" +
            "prefix dbpedia-owl:<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>" +
            "prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>" +
            "SELECT * WHERE { " +
            "    SERVICE <http://141.117.3.88:8890/sparql> { " +
            "select ?Concept where { ?Concept a dbpedia-owl:Film. ?Concept rdfs:label ?label. FILTER (strStarts(str(?label), 'Inception')). } limit 10" +
            "    }" +
            "}" ;
    LogCtl.setCmdLogging();
    Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString) ;
    try(QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, ModelFactory.createDefaultModel())) {
        ResultSet rs = qexec.execSelect();
        result = (ResultSetFormatter.asText(rs));
    }
    return result;
```

I am getting  Error HttpException: 400 and I don't know why.
Thanks!

Comment: What's at `http://141.117.3.88:8890/sparql`?  If you're trying to query against DBpedia, would `http://dbpedia.org/sparql` make more sense?

Comment: http://141.117.3.88:8890/sparql is very similar to dbpedia that is specific for our lab. The thing is I know it works because when I query "select ?Concept ?type where { ?Concept rdf:type ?type.  Filter regex(?type, '.*?Film.*?'). ?Concept rdfs:label ?label. FILTER regex(?label, '" + jenaString +"', 'i'). }" it works.  So I know the query in my original code works and I know the service works but they are not working together..

Comment: the query inside the service block in your original code does *not* work on the endpoint that you mentioned.  I showed the output in my answer;  you get an error.

Answer (score 2):

Your query may work at DBpedia, but the part that's supposed to be executed on `http://141.117.3.88:8890/sparql` doesn't work at `http://141.117.3.88:8890/sparql`.  If you try running

```sql
prefix rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix dbpedia-owl:<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

select ?Concept where {
  ?Concept a dbpedia-owl:Film.
  ?Concept rdfs:label ?label.
  FILTER (strStarts(str(?label), 'Inception')).
}
```

[SPARQL Results (an error message)](http://141.117.3.88:8890/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=prefix%20rdfs%3A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0Aprefix%20rdf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0D%0Aprefix%20dbpedia-owl%3A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0Aprefix%20xsd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aselect%20%3FConcept%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3FConcept%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3AFilm.%0D%0A%20%20%3FConcept%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel.%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28strStarts%28str%28%3Flabel%29%2C%20%27Inception%27%29%29.%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on)

there, you get:

```
Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 11: syntax error at 'strStarts' before '('

SPARQL query:
define sql:big-data-const 0 
#output-format:text/html
define sql:signal-void-variables 1 prefix rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix dbpedia-owl:<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

select ?Concept where {
  ?Concept a dbpedia-owl:Film.
  ?Concept rdfs:label ?label.
  FILTER (strStarts(str(?label), 'Inception')).
}
```

The about text for the server says:

> Copyright © 2015 OpenLink Software Virtuoso version 06.01.3127 on
>   Linux (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu), Single Server Edition

Perhaps that version of Virtuoso doesn't support all the SPARQL 1.1 functions?  You'd need to check the Virtuoso documentation, but based on *[Does Virtuoso versions <=6.0 support SPARQL 1.1?](http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/11843/does-virtuoso-versions-60-support-sparql-11)*, it sounds like the version you've got, 6.01, may not support SPARQL 1.1 completely.  The public DBpedia endpoint, on the other hand, [is running a 7.x version](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?help=intro):

> Copyright © 2015 OpenLink Software Virtuoso version 07.20.3213 on
>   Linux (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-FX2), Single Server Edition

Comment: `SELECT?Concept where { ?Concept a dbpedia-owl:Film. ?Concept rdfs:label ?label. FILTER (strStarts(str(?label), 'Inception')). } limit 10`   This is working on [link](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) and [link](http://dbpedia-live.openlinksw.com/sparql) and the output is Concept
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Inception...  But I guess the problem is, as you said, different versions.. I guess I'll hacve to use another function.  Thanks, really appreciate it!

Comment: Yes, that query works on DBpedia's endpoing, but neither of those is what you've got in your SERVICE in the query.  In you're code, you're using `http://141.117.3.88:8890/sparql`, which is running an older version of Virtuoso, as I explained in my answer.